# Simple mileage algorithm - throwing weird error?

Tags: java, loops, split

The code below takes `n` inputs (-1 to exit). For each input, user enters a space separated string of the miles per hour and the hour they are at. Hours increase as new data is entered.

Sample input:

```
1

20 2

30 6

10 7

-1
```

Sample output:

```
170 miles (20*2 + 30*(6-2) + 10*(7-6))
```

The code:

```java
package mypackage;

import java.io.*;

public class SpeedLimit {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        while (n != -1) {
            int miles = 0;
            int hours = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                String s = reader.readLine();
                String[] parts = s.split(" "); // mph hrs
                miles += Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * (Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) - hours);
                hours += Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            }
            System.out.println(miles + " miles");
            n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }
    }

}
```

Error I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30 6"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at changemyname.SpeedLimit.main(SpeedLimit.java:21)
```

How is this possible?

Comment: You have two loops that use `n` as the end condition. Outer loop repeats until `n` is -1 and inner repeats from 1 to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked and ran your code and it worked perfectly fine.

- Note that you have to first provide an `integer` value without spaces.

> int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

If there were any spaces then an error would come because you cannot convert a `String` with spaces to an `int`. So, it should definitely be a value without spaces or any other non-numerical values.

e.g.:
32 - Correct
24 5 - Wrong
3h - Wrong...

- `While loop` will check whether the value equals **-1** and if not it enters to the `for loop`. It again asks the user to input **pairs of values**.

e.g.:
12 3
15 8

The loop will repeat `n` times. (`n` is the value you entered earlier.)

- Then, your program will display the total number of miles.
- Then, again it asks for the `n` value and repeat the process. You should enter **-1** to exit from looping and program.

**I think you have made some mistake in typing values. Make sure to input your values in appropriate manner.**

Answer (score 0):

Please take a closer look at the condition of your loops, and how you are taking in inputs.

As far as the space separated inputs go, there could be more than one space between them.

Try this:

```
String[] parts = s.split("\\s+");
```

This will split any number of consecutive spaces.